# How do I prevent Spork from preloading my routes file in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, devise, spork

Spork is preloading my `User` model, but not any of my other models. (I.e., I have to restart the Spork server every time I make changes to `app/models/user.rb`.)

Running `spork --diagnose` tells me that the problem is being caused by Devise. As spork preloads `config/routes.rb`, it runs the line `devise_for :users` which preloads the User model.

So how can I prevent this from happening? [This page](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujitsu) in the Spork documentatation says I should use `::trap_method`, by putting into my `spec_helper` file either the line

```
Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application, :reload_routes!)
```

for Rails < 3.1, or

```
Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application::RoutesReloader, :reload!)
```

for Rails 3.1. But I've tried both of these and neither of them work. I'm running Rails 4.0.0 and Spork 1.0.0rc4.

How do I get the User class to reload with each run?

Comment: Can you include the stack trace for running spork --diagnose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spec/spec_helper.rb reload the models explicitly:

```
Spork.each_run do
  # reload all the models
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/*.rb"].each do |model|
    load model
  end
end
```

Comment: Agh, so simple! Thanks. (I just added the line `load Rails.root.join "app", "models", "user.rb" as there's no need to reload every model - it's just User that wasn't working properly.)